# Single Sign On Jsp & get remote user name

Tags: java, jsp, authentication, windows-authentication

We have a requirement where we need to get the remote user windows userName.

I tried to use NTLM Authenticaion but it doesn't work , it gives me the server's windows user name.

Can anybody suggest me solution?

Comment: You tried NTLM.  Oh that's nice.  How did you try NTLM exactly?

Comment: I tried the basic functionality of NTLMAuthentication, geting the username but it gets me the user name of the server of the system where application is deployed.

Comment: NTLM is Microsoft, so how are you interfacing it with Java? You need to provide some code or something (library name used maybe) or nobody can really help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use spnego which does Kerberos authentication which is more advance and secure than NTLM. Try [Spnego Filter](http://spnego.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Isn't there any other way to get remote user name other than using this framework. is it possible with jquery?

Comment: No, jQuery is used for client side javascript but you need the user name in the server side.